# Java programs are being run in the background itself even though i called the functions in the scenario outline in karate- cucumber

Tags: api, automation, web-api-testing, karate

I needed to provide a delay between the two http calls, so i have created a java program and invoked the script between the two http calls in the scenario outline, But the java program is being executed in the background. Could some help in this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I strongly discourage you from depending on Java code like this - because you will not be able to get the benefits of Karate's unique approach.

Here's how you can use Java seamlessly from within Karate itself:

```
* def sleep = function(millis){ java.lang.Thread.sleep(millis) }
* print 'sleeping...'
* call sleep 5000
* print 'resumed'
```

So once you have the `function` defined in say the `Background`, you can re-use it easily, that too with different values.

It also sounds to me that you might be better off using polling, so do look at this also as a reference: [`polling.feature`](https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/karate-demo/src/test/java/demo/polling/polling.feature)

Comment: @SivaSankar - if it did, do you mind accepting the answer and up-voting ? It helps keep the quality of answers on this site. I think you are new to SO :)

Comment: How do i do that?

Comment: see if you can figure it out, use the up arrow, search for the word "accept" etc. else never mind.